# Android: findViewById function in different class and different package

Tags: android, eclipse

I am making an app, I know I will have to getText() from EditText lots of times as I go along, I don't want to declare EditText every time and get it's value, so I want to have a shortcut function.

I have a package called : als.helpers (has all my shortcuts, SharedPreference functions etc..) and I have main als.appName class which contains actual code of app.

So I have this class:

```
package als.helpers;

import android.content.Context;
import android.webkit.WebView.FindListener;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ShortcutFunc {
    Context context;

    public ShortcutFunc(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String getTextValue(int id){
        EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(id);
        return et.getText().toString();

    }


}
```

However - even without running app, eclipse marks findViewById() as invalid. How do I solve this? and what's this caused by?

Comment: Can you mention, what exactly error you are getting in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is that `findViewById` is not some kind of global function but a method of `Activity` instances. It works in your activity because it translates to `this.findViewById`.

Use something like this

```
public static String getTextValue(Activity act, int id){
    EditText et = (EditText) act.findViewById(id);
    return et.getText().toString();
}
```

You can store the reference of the activity in a field, but that may lead to memory leaks...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
public String getTextValue(int id){
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(id);
    return et.getText().toString();

}
```

use your `ActivityContext` context which you have already passed trough the `constructor` to find the View.

```
public String getTextValue(int id){
    EditText et = (EditText) context.findViewById(id);
    return et.getText().toString();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the parent activity/view reference to the function and call using `activity.findViewById(id)` or `view.findViewById(id)`